# Securely logging out as any user

Tags: security, logout

When using the functionality where the system admin can [log in as any user](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2012/06/log-in-as-any-user-without-first-having-access-granted-new-feature-in-summer-12.html), I noticed that during log-out, there are two different responses that I can get back from `/secur/logout.jsp`. The most common one conveniently takes me back to the user page, but there is one that logs me out, and causes the browser to generate a warning since it tries to run javascript to submit a form to the root url over plain http.

I grabbed the sid from the request cookies, and an attempt at a rest api request about a minute later showed the session id had already been invalidated at that point at least, but this warning message still makes me a little uneasy. Are there any security concerns with clicking continue and sending that request without TLS?

**Occasional response that logs me out and javascript-redirects over http**

[image]

**Typical response that takes me back to the user page**

[image]